# HttpClient complains about concurrent IO read and write operations

Tags: f#, httpclient

I have an F# funciton that uses a static instance of HttpClient:

```
let executeRequest request =
    async {
        let! response = StaticHttpClient.Instance.SendAsync(request) |> Async.AwaitTask
        let! stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        return (stream, response.StatusCode)
    }
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

When the request body is large, the function often throws an AggregateException with inner exception "NotSupportedException: The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations."

I wonder why this happens. Looks like there is an attempt to use response stream before the request is stream is fully processed. But why?

Comment: Can it be that the continuation is executed on a different thread and that is what the `HttpClient` is complaining about? Have you checked the conditions for when this exception is thrown?

Comment: I will check continuation conditions thanks.

Comment: Since the `HttpClient` instance is static, is it accessed from more than one thread? If so, could it be that it reuses the same response and stream objects? Only guessing here...

Comment: Since this happens inside the actor, there should not be thread-related problems. But once thing that may be interesting to check: apparently the exception was raised when the HTTP call failed with 500 error. Not 100% sure but quite probable. I will try to reproduce failing condition and see if the error happens again.